# Select Data From Table Without Multiple Of The Same User ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select all the elements where x_id=1 but there will be multiple rows for that result with the same user_id and I just want it to show one result for each user id (instead of multiple). How would I be able to do this in SQL im completely lost?

Table:

### a

id | x_id | user_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table WHERE x_id = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

select distinct user_id from a where x_id = 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.user_id
  FROM a a
 WHERE a.x_id = 1
 GROUP BY a.user_id
```

-- or --

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_id
  FROM a a
 WHERE a.x_id = 1
```

These return an equivalent result set.  My personal preference is to use the `GROUP BY`, because I sometimes want to return a count of the number of rows, or use some other aggregate function, which I can't do with the DISTINCT.